# Using tikz to merge axes with a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, arrows

In the MWE below I want to add a $t$ at the tip of the arrow of the horizontal arrow and an $x$ at the tip of vertical arrow.

Also I want the arrows to be so that they meet with the diagbox slash automatically. As is this is done by trial and error. In other words, I want to replace the customary vertical and horizontal line separators, had there been a c|c and \hline in the table, with arrows.

The actual table is populated with formulas and is bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c  c    c   c   c  c c}
\diagbox{$i$}{$j$} \tikzmark{a}& $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$  &  $4$  &  $5$ \\
\tikzmark{c}&&&&&& \tikzmark{d}\\
-2& . & .&. &. & .  &  . \\
-1& . &. &. &. & .  & .  \\
 0& .& .  &. &.&. &  . \\
 1& .&.&  . & .  & . &. \\
 2& .&. & .& .& . & . \\
 3    \tikzmark{b}& .& .&. & .& .&.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(c.north east)+
(-0.9,0.15)$) -- ($(d.north west)+(0.7,0.15)$);
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] ($(a.north)+(0.25,0.5)$) 
-- ($(b.south)+(0.45,-0.2)$);
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add nodes at the end of  a path, e.g. `\draw (a) -- (b) node[right] {$x$};`. Don't know how to do the positioning automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one approach.

I place some reference "tikzmarks" at strategic points:

- `t` at top of the table (by using `\tikzmark` in a line before the tabular)
- `b` at bottom of the table (by using `\tikzmark` in a line after the tabular)
- `l` at the left of the table (by using `\tikzmkark` just before the tabular)
- `r` at the right of the table (by using `\tikzmark` just after the tabular)
- `x` at the end of the diagonal line. This was the trickier. I used an extra row after the tabular headings, but placed with no vertical space (by using `\\[-8pt]` after the headings), and placed a left-aligned cell in the second column without padding (by using `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}`, and a tikzmark inside that cell.

The following figure shows the placement of these strategic points:

[image: Control points]

The above figure was produced by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \coordinate (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\tikzmark{t}\\
\tikzmark{l}
\begin{tabular}{c   c     c     c     c     c     c}
\diagbox{$i$}{$j$}& $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$\\[-8pt]
 & \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tikzmark{x}}\\
-2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
-1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 0 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 3 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{tabular}\tikzmark{r}\\
\tikzmark{b}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] {
    \fill[red] (l) circle(2pt) node[left] {l};
    \fill[red] (r) circle(2pt) node[right] {r};
    \fill[red] (x) circle(2pt) node[below right] {x};
    \fill[red] (t) circle(2pt) node[above] {t};
    \fill[red] (b) circle(2pt) node[below] {b};
}
\end{document}
```

Once these strategic points are in place, you can use the syntax `(t-|l)` for example, to refer to the coordinate which is horizontally aligned with "top" and vertically aligned with "left". This would be the upper-left corner of the table.

Using this syntax appropriately with points `l`, `r` and `x` you can draw the horizontal arrow. Using `t`, `b` and `x` you can draw the vertical arrow. As follows:

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] (x-|l) -- (x-|r) node[right] {$t$};
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[-triangle 45] (t-|x) -- (b-|x) node[below] {$x$};
```

To get:

[image: Result]

## Update

In an edition of the question the OP added the possibility of having other vertical or horizontal rules in the table, also to be replaced by arrows.

The same approach used above can be extended to this case. You have to place additional tikzmarks at the rows you want to have an horizontal arrow below (instead of putting `\hrule` after these), and to the columns you want to have a vertical arrow before (instead of putting `|` in the format table declaration before them.

To simplify this, the following macros can be defined:

```
\newcommand{\columnmark}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\tikzmark{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\rowmark}[1]{%
  \\[-8pt]\tikzmark{#1}
}
```

Which can be used for example like this to define two control points (`c1` and `c2`) to add vertical arrows before some columns, and two control points (`r1` and `r2`) do add horizontal arrows after some rows:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\tikzmark{t}\\
\tikzmark{l}
\begin{tabular}{c   c     c     c     c     c     c   c    c }
\diagbox{$i$}{$j$}& $0$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$\\[-8pt]
 & \columnmark{x} & & & \columnmark{c1} & & & \columnmark{c2} & \\
-2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
-1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 0 & . & . & . & . & . & . \rowmark{r1}\\
 1 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 2 & . & . & . & . & . & . \\
 3 & . & . & . & . & . & . \rowmark{r2}\\
 \\
\end{tabular}\tikzmark{r}\\
\tikzmark{b}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Then you can draw the arrows using the `(X-|Z)` syntax already seen. In this case:

```
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[-triangle 45] (x-|l) -- (x-|r) node[right] {$t$};
  \draw[-triangle 45] (t-|x) -- (b-|x) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw[-triangle 45] (r1-|l) -- (r1-|r);
  \draw[-triangle 45] (r2-|l) -- (r2-|r);
  \draw[-triangle 45] (t-|c1) -- (b-|c1);
  \draw[-triangle 45] (t-|c2) -- (b-|c2);
}
```

would produce:

[image: Result]

Comment: I run into a problem when several of these tables are in a paper. The axes separate from the table  and show on one page while the body of the table shows up in another page. As if there is a sort of a float issue. The table moves to another page but somehow tikz does not now the new location. Any ideas?

Comment: @Maesumi Try moving the `\tikz[overlay, remember picture]` part which draws the arrows so that it is inside the same `table` float which uses the tikz marks. This way it should "float" too to the same page.